# Vectorizing or boosting time for an interpolation in Python

Tags: python, vectorization, interpolation

I have to boost the time for an interpolation over a large (NxMxT) matrix `MTR`, where:

- N is about 8000;
- M is about 10000;
- T represents the number of times at which each NxM matrix is calculated (in my case it's 23).

I have to compute the interpolation element-wise, on all the T different times, and return the interpolated values over a different array of times (`T_interp`, in my case with lenght 47) so, as output, I want an NxMxT_interp matrix.

The code snippet below defines the function I built for the interpolation, using `scipy.interpolate.Rbf` (`y` is the array `MTR[i,j,:]`, `x` is the times array with length T, `x_interp` is the new array of times with length T_interp:

```
#==============================================================================
    # Interpolate without nans
#==============================================================================
def interp(x,y,x_interp,**kwargs):
        import numpy as np
        from scipy.interpolate import Rbf
        mask = np.isnan(y)
        y_mask = np.ma.array(y,mask = mask)
        x_new = [x[i] for i in np.where(~mask)[0]]
        if len(y_mask.compressed()) == 0:
                return [np.nan for i,n in enumerate(x_interp)]
        elif len(y_mask.compressed()) == 1:
                return [y_mask.compressed() for i,n in enumerate(x_interp)]
        interp = Rbf(x_new,y_mask.compressed(),**kwargs)
        y_interp = interp(x_interp)
        return y_interp
```

I tried to achieve my goal either by looping over the NxM elements of the `MTR` matrix:

```
new_MTR = np.empty((N,M,T_interp))
for i in range(N):
        for j in range(M):
                new_MTR[i,j,:]=interp(times,MTR[i,j,:],New_times,function = 'linear')
```

or by using the `np.apply_along_axis` funtion:

```
new_MTR = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: interp(times,x,New_times,function = 'linear'),2,MTR)
```

In both cases I extimated the time it takes to perform the whole operation and it appears to be slightly better for the `np.apply_along_axis` function, but still it will take about 15 hours!!

Is there a way to reduce this time? Maybe by vectorizing the entire operation? I don't know much about vectorizing and how it can be done in a situation like mine so any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Use a language other than Python?

Comment: I would like to achieve the results in Python if possible, first because I don't know any faster languages (like C or C++ for example) and then this script isi embedded in a bigger script so things would be easier for the person who is gonna use (or edit) the script itself..

Comment: Try out `numba`